# What is mms protocol and how do I enable it?

Tags: vlc

What is mms protocol and how do I enable it?

Specific protocol is missing when I try play internet radio stream on VLC.

Stream of code if someone can make some sense of it: https://pastebin.com/QQeuaQq3

Comment: [Cross-posted on U&L](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/515701). It is to be noted that [cross posting is discouraged on stack exchange network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/468333)

Answer (score 0):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Media_Server

Try `audacious` or `parole` for playing mms streams in Ubuntu 18.04.

With some player (such as VLC) you might have luck, if you replace "mms" by non-standard "mmsh" in URI.

Note: Starting of playing mms stream might be slow by `audacious`: [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/audacious/+bug/1829986)